# FileMerge utility (part of Xcode) Help reports "Help Viewer cannot open this content"

Tags: xcode, folders

I'm new to using Xcode and just discovered that it includes a utility, FileMerge, to visually compare two folders, or in the case of Xcode, two project.

But the FileMerge Help seems to be broken. When I open it, it will show a list of suggested topics, but selecting any of them, or searching for anything else, generates either a totally blank page or the popup message "Help Viewer cannot open this content".

It's not the entire Help Viewer system. I can open Xcode Help and TextEdit help and even navigate within the help viewer from one to the other, see generic Mac help, etc. But if I search for FileMerge, I get several results and every one of them takes me to a blank page.

I digging for solutions to this problem, there don't seem to be any more recent than MacOS 10.6 or Xcode 5. I'm on Catalina (10.15) running Xcode 11.3.

I found one suggested solution which notes that TinkerTools System 4 has a utility to fix the Help System. But that tool is no longer available as of 2021 (due to not being compatible with 64 bit systems, I think).

Could it be that virtually everyone ignores that FileMerge Help is broken because no one uses FileMerge because there's a much more useful and robust third-party, free utility out there?

How can either fix the FileMerge help so that I can found out how FileMerge works or find another tool that will do the job of comparing two versions of an Xcode project?